# Running TestCases in JUnit on Ubuntu

Tags: java, junit, tdd, ubuntu-10.04

I am coming from Python world, so please forgive my ignorance. I am trying to learn TDD with JUnit framework in Java. I am following the method described by daniel kullmann in following thread: [How to install Junit][1].

The steps I am following are:

1. Writing Test Cases
2. Running command **javac -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar Test.java**
3. then **java -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test**

So far So good. But my question is:

1. Do I need to run both full line of command when I have to test my class ? I mean can't it be **javac Test.java** and **java Test** ? I have exported the path in .bashrc as below:

   export JUNIT_HOME=/usr/share/java

   export PATH=$JUNIT_HOME/junit4.jar:org.junit.runner.JUnitCore:${PATH}
2. I have downloaded latest junit framework 4-11 and kept at location /usr/local/JUNIT. But when I am running command **java -cp /usr/local/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test**, its giving the error below:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
   at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
   at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:96)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:47)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:40)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLC
   ```

Can someone please guide me.
[1]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/64213/how-to-install-use-junit

Comment: Hi, looks like you forgot to add the hamcrest-core.jar library. It is available on the download site https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Why do you make your life that hard by not using an IDE?

Comment: during some programming course in the university, one of the requirements was do not use any IDE during the development (only vi or something similar). So, in some cases IDEs are not available

Comment: @ Cyril Deba: Added paths in .bashrc but with no luck: export JUNIT_HOME=/user/local/JUNIT
export PATH=$JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.11.jar:$JUNIT_HOME/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:${PATH}

Comment: @André: As I mentioned, I am coming from Python world. So no idea what is the best way to do TDD in Java. I will look into some IDEs for it.

Comment: @CyrilDeba I'm aware of that. Just wanted to hear OPs specific reasons.

Comment: @SRC I recommend Eclipse. It has great support for JUnit build in. Also the dependency/build path management is very good. I always find it very inconvenient to do that stuff in a terminal.

Comment: @André:Sure.will look into Eclipse. Normally I have worked with Vim and sublime.

Comment: If you do it via the console you need to run both lines. The first one compiles your source and the second one runs your test. There are many ways how you can simplify, such as using an IDE, maven, ant, ... But the easiest and for sure allowed by your course is writing a shell script.